# WebView wont load only on API 23 "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>"

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Page loads o older and newer apis, but on api 23 i just get this and it will never load `I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(27)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>", source: https:/...`

```
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webView.settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)

    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        ...
    }

    webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        ...
    }

    webView.loadUrl(url)
```

Comment: This message seems to be coming from the Javascript console log within the webview. Please include the whole content of the webpage, especially the contents of the file in the `source: https://...` url. (Provided you excluded the url for simplicity only)